# Why does Outlook replace my image tags with broken img tags in my email template?

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, image

I was creating a simple email with some images. It looks very well in gmail (tested with Firefox , Google Chrome and even IE 9), but not in Outlook where my original img tags are replaced with random img tags like

> `<img src="http://part3.06070903.04020009@xxxxx.com">`

xxxx = my business name.

It also when in the html I type `<td height="20"></td>` just for margin purpose, I get a `<br>` inside of it in both gmail and outlook.
This is so weird because I didn't have these problems before when working with emails.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this List of supported will be of some help to you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx

Generally the biggest differences lie between Outlook 2007/2010 which use an old word renderer due to legal reasons and the other Outlook versions.

For the empty tags, that get filled with <br>-Tags i would recommend trying a &#160; or &nbsp; as placeholder content to suppress the <br>.